# How to show bootstrap affix position:fix with in .container for the .nav-tabs?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, sticky

bootstrap affix works fine but unfortunately the sticky tab does not show with in the `.container` it display as full width. Is there any option to fit `nav-tabs`with in the container ?

Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vOyZGq

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#details-dropdown li a').click(function(e) {
    window.location = this.hash;
    $("#details-menu li").removeClass("active");
    $('#details-menu li a[href="' + $(this).attr('href') + '"]').parent().addClass('active');
  });

  $('#details-menu').affix({
    offset: {
      top: $("#details-menu").offset().top
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#details-menu {
  z-index: 99;
  background-color: #fff;
}
#details-menu.affix {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
.tab-content {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-top: none;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#mynav">
  <div class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mynav">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#details">Details</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">My details <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="details-dropdown">
              <li role="presentation"><a href="#myabout" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">About</a>
              </li>
              <li role="presentation"><a href="#myprofile" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">Profile</a>
              </li>
              <li role="presentation"><a href="#mymessage" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">Messages</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12" id="home">
        <div class="jumbotron form-group">
          <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Non magnam eius voluptatum dignissimos aspernatur quas ab, consequuntur aliquid earum veniam. Fuga maiores possimus distinctio unde quae, corrupti perspiciatis adipisci, inventore!</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1>My details</h1>
        <ul role="tablist" class="nav nav-tabs" id="details-menu">
          <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#myabout" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">About</a>
          </li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#myprofile" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">Profile</a>
          </li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#mymessage" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">Messages</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="myabout">
            <h1>About</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum soluta numquam voluptate repellendus minima, porro, reiciendis explicabo iste expedita neque quidem voluptates dignissimos! Tempore odio vel, natus ipsa alias temporibus.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet nobis iste velit veniam perferendis non sunt labore ad, aliquid eius voluptate nostrum impedit quia quo consequuntur sit. Quam asperiores, ex.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio, quisquam adipisci. Distinctio perferendis repudiandae recusandae totam eligendi! Dicta eveniet facilis impedit porro cumque iusto culpa non eum error voluptas. Esse!</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero rerum laboriosam, mollitia repudiandae inventore ea, voluptas harum nihil. Earum beatae tempore necessitatibus unde, deleniti rem recusandae dicta ut impedit dolore!</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur cupiditate natus quos incidunt pariatur saepe laudantium minima ipsam vero, illum vitae sint nisi consequuntur tempore repudiandae magnam placeat, quidem dolorum?</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur cupiditate natus quos incidunt pariatur saepe laudantium minima ipsam vero, illum vitae sint nisi consequuntur tempore repudiandae magnam placeat, quidem dolorum?</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur cupiditate natus quos incidunt pariatur saepe laudantium minima ipsam vero, illum vitae sint nisi consequuntur tempore repudiandae magnam placeat, quidem dolorum?</p>
          </div>
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="myprofile">
            <h2>Profile</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur cupiditate natus quos incidunt pariatur saepe laudantium minima ipsam vero, illum vitae sint nisi consequuntur tempore repudiandae magnam placeat, quidem dolorum?</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur cupiditate natus quos incidunt pariatur saepe laudantium minima ipsam vero, illum vitae sint nisi consequuntur tempore repudiandae magnam placeat, quidem dolorum?</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur cupiditate natus quos incidunt pariatur saepe laudantium minima ipsam vero, illum vitae sint nisi consequuntur tempore repudiandae magnam placeat, quidem dolorum?</p>
          </div>
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="mymessage">
            <h2>Message</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur cupiditate natus quos incidunt pariatur saepe laudantium minima ipsam vero, illum vitae sint nisi consequuntur tempore repudiandae magnam placeat, quidem dolorum?</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur cupiditate natus quos incidunt pariatur saepe laudantium minima ipsam vero, illum vitae sint nisi consequuntur tempore repudiandae magnam placeat, quidem dolorum?</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur cupiditate natus quos incidunt pariatur saepe laudantium minima ipsam vero, illum vitae sint nisi consequuntur tempore repudiandae magnam placeat, quidem dolorum?</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```